# Python persistent socket connection

Tags: python, sockets, persistence, file-descriptor

I'm new to python :) I would like to create persistent socket. I tried to do this using file descriptors. What I tried is:

1. Open a socket socket connection `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`
2. Get it's file descriptor number `fd = s.fileno()`
3. Open the file descriptor as I/O `os.open(fd)`

But I get `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`

I said I'm new to python and maybe I'm wrong with the implementation. But I tried a simpler example `os.close(s.fileno())` and I get the same error `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`

I found an example written in ruby and I tested it, it works. [How do I make persistent network sockets on Unix in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592/how-do-i-make-persistent-network-sockets-on-unix-in-ruby)

Can any one write this into python for me, what I want to achieve is:
socket_start.py google.com (thie will print the fd number)
sleep 10
socket_write.py fd_number 'something'
sleep 10
socket_read.py fd_number 1024

I hope you understand what I want to do. Thanks in advice!

---

After your responses I tried next code:

## 1

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('google.com', 80))
s.send('GET /\n')
print s.fileno()
```

## 2

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

fd = int(sys.argv[1])
os.read(fd, 1024)
```

And the error is `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`

I'm sure what the problem is (I'm a php developer). I think same as php, python deletes garbage after closing a script. How to solve this in python ?

Comment: Andrew, note that the ruby example that you post does not do what you want. It catches SIGINT and then immediately respawns itself. This is different than dying, waiting ten seconds and then expecting that the python (if not the OS) has not reclaimed the file descriptor. This is not to mention that the process that the ruby example passes the file descriptor to is a subprocess of the file that opens the socket.

Answer (score 1):

You use [os.fdopen()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#file-object-creation) to open file descriptors.

I'm actually surprised that you got that far because `os.open` requires a filename **and** flags stating which mode to open the file in. for example `fd = os.open('foo.txt', os.O_RONLY)`. As my example indicates, it *returns* a file descriptor rather than accepting one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-create the socket by a parameter received on the commandline (i.e., the socket), use `socket.fromfd`